# Creating an NTFS folder with read/write, but not "edit", permissions

Tags: file-permissions, ntfs

If you start with "read, execute, write" basic permissions and take away "create folders/append data" you get a "drop folder" with read and "write new files only", but applications "save as" functions are unable to save files here.  I can presume why... because it creates the file first then tries to rewrite it.  Grant it, you can still drag'n'drop or copy/paste new files... but saving directly to this folder from a program fails.  Is there a way to create such a folder that doesn't break the save-as function?

Comment: hmm, generally speaking, the "save as" feature shows you a small file explorer window and expects that you browse **into** the target folder, no ?

Comment: Yes. Folder access is not a problem.  "List folder contents" is granted with read/execute.

Comment: You can use [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor what's going on when saving